# Is it good to use AnyObject for accepting an array of elements of any type in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to create a method uniq which takes an array but element type can be different for example [1, "Hello", true, 234.3] or all element types can be same [1, 2, 3, 4]

```
func uniq(array: AnyObject[]) -> AnyObject[] {
    ...
}
```

Is it best practice to use AnyObject and return AnyObject array?

Also can I compare two AnyObjects using an == equality sign and it will compare them regardless of them being the same type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics to create typed functions that can accept any type without resorting to upcasting to `AnyObject`, i.e:

```
func uniq<T>(array: T[]) -> T[] {
    ...
}
```

To be able to be able to compare the items you can add a generic constraint to ensure all types that call this method conforms to the `Equatable` protocol, which will allow you to use `==` against the items, i.e:

```
func uniq<T : Equatable>(array: T[]) -> T[] {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining both of your questions, use

```
func uniq (array: Equatable[]) -> Equatable[] { ... }
```

Detail: You can't compare objects of type `AnyObject` with `==` because `==` requires objects to conform to the `Equatable` protocol; not all objects do.

As @mythz said, you could use:

```
func uniq<T> (array: T[]) -> T[] { ... }
```

but then every time you use `uniq` on an array of arbitrary objects you would need to call the method with:

```
uniq<AnyObject> (someArray)
```

You may be fine with that, especially if you sometimes want to use `uniq()` with uniformly typed objects (Int, Double, ..., Equatable).  If you just want a function that works for any types, any time, then your suggestion of:

```
func uniq (array: AnyObject[]) -> AnyObject[]) { ... }
```

is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In a statically typed language, it's not a best practice to use a type like `AnyObject`: it indicates that you're throwing type safety out the window. If your design is relying on `AnyObject`, you may want to rethink the design.

`Any` and `AnyObject` should be thought of as a necessary evil: the need to interoperate with dynamically-typed Objective-C frameworks. To be forward-looking, the aim should be to avoid their use as much as possible.

For the second part of your question, GoZoner's answer is excellent.